# ajax refresh to display new posts

Tags: ajax

i want to display new posts in a specific page in condition that when new post published the page refresh by ajax and display new post such as living blogging.
this is my code of specific page

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Ajax
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>  
        <!--main-->
        <div class="main container-fluid">
            <section class="m-sidebar col-md-10 col-xs-12">
                <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/ads.php'); ?>
                <div class="col-xs-12" id="content">
                    <div class="article">   
                        <ul style="color: #e73c40;">
<?php 
$my_custom_query= new WP_Query(array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'cat'   =>  '۱',
'order' => 'DESC',
'orderby' => 'ID',
'posts_per_page' =>'10',
'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1 
)); ?> 
<?php 
if($my_custom_query->have_posts()) : ?>
<?php 
while($my_custom_query->have_posts()) : $my_custom_query->the_post();?> 
                                <li><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></li>
                            <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/l-sidebar.php'); ?>

        </div>
        <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

this is a demo
 http://www.shahrekhabar.com/%D9%BE%D8%AE%D8%B4-%D8%B2%D9%86%D8%AF%D9%87-%D8%A7%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1

Comment: I can read what you want to do, nothing about the problem you have to do it. Can you please edit the question and explain what your problem is?

Comment: i need help to create a auto refresh page by ajax

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/load-posts-ajax/) guide to write an ajax request for your homepage. It's plenty self explanatory.

Then, using `jQuery`, make request to the website every 30 seconds or so. There is no way to notify a client about a post being published, the client itself has to check whether there is a new post published or not.

After you have created some code, you can update the question with technical information and i will update the answer for you.